# Update Dgraph in real time via Flink

Tags: database, graph, apache-flink

I am searching for a low latency graph DB which allows for in depth queries, while being updated in real time. 
Is it possible to update Dgraph in real time through Flink processes?
I would like to validate an idea as follows:

1. read stream in Kafka pass to Flink to create Data Table / Graph
2. pass the data Table / Graph to Dgraph along with edge / vertices attributes
3. update Dgraph in real time ( edge / vertices attributes )
4. copy / Lift the latest version of Dgraph to Flink to perform computations (periodically)

If impossible: Dgraph is based on RocksDB, does anyone know if data can be passed via RocksDB to Dgraph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe sounds straight forward, Dgraph should be able to do those operations. Is the concern around high throughput, i.e. whether Dgraph would be able to take the mutation and query load thrown by Flink?

The main issue that you might run into here is that the data would need to be converted into RDF format for mutations, and the queries would need to be in GraphQL-like format that we use.

For more documentation, you can see our wiki: https://wiki.dgraph.io/Main_Page

Also, happy to understand your specific use case and give more detailed answers here: https://discuss.dgraph.io